# Как сделать выбранную ссылку другим цветом?

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax

Есть вот такой вот кусок кода в файле .php, в нем ajax-код, который меняет контент. Нужно чтоб ссылки меняли цвет, когда выдлелялись.  Прописал в CSS-файле, но что-то не срабатывает.....Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я что неправильно делаю?

CSS:

```
/*
a:checked {
color: red;
text-decoration: underline;
}

.loadBtn  a:active {
color: #f00; 
}
*/
.activeEv{
color: #f00; /* Цвет активной ссылки */
}
```

File .php :

```
    <body>
    <ul>
    <li  class="loadBtn">page1</li>
    <li  class="loadBtn">page2</li>
    <li  class="loadBtn">page3</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var tpls = ['page1.php', 'page2.php',  'page3.php'];

                $('.loadBtn').click(function(){
           $('.loadBtn').removeClass('activeEv');
           $(this).addClass('activeEv');
                    loadContent($(this).index());
                });
                loadContent(0);

                function loadContent(index) {
                    if (!tpls[index]) return;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: tpls[index],
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("#content").html(html);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Выбранная ссылка — это как? Посещенная?

Comment: ваш код выглядит рабочим, скорее всего ошибка не в этом, проверьте вывод ошибок в консоли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете при `click` задать определённый класс активной ссылке

```
.activeEv{
color: #f00; /* Цвет активной ссылки */
}



 <body>
    <ul>
    <li  class="loadBtn">page1</li>
    <li  class="loadBtn">page2</li>
    <li  class="loadBtn">page3</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var tpls = ['page1.php', 'page2.php',  'page3.php'];

                $('.loadBtn').click(function(){
$('.loadBtn').removeClass('activeEv');
$(this).addClass('activeEv');
                    loadContent($(this).index());
                });
                loadContent(0);

                function loadContent(index) {
                    if (!tpls[index]) return;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: tpls[index],
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("#content").html(html);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Хм....сделал ВСЁ, как Вы написали......ничего не изменилось....

Comment: как не изменилось? новый клас для loadBtn  задаётся? может у вас  в стилях есть другие цвета для loadBtn ?

Comment: добавил Ваши изменения (и в код в вопросе), ничего не изменилось....

Comment: вы что то не так делаете, на скорую руку скопировал код, посмотрите   https://jsfiddle.net/L5k30mvo/
вы не ответили на вопрос, в вашем коде  новый клас для loadBtn задаётся?

Comment: Arsen, один раз задается у меня класс loadBtn

Comment: @Александр вам надо показать ваш изменённый код, чтобы понять где и что вы не так делаете. Вы проверили как код должен работать на  http://jsfiddle.net/L5k30mvo  ??

Comment: Arsen, все как у Вас! но только не срабатывает.....перекопипастил Ваш код,но все равно не срабатывает.....

Comment: но вы хоть сможете скопировать ваш код например на  http://jsfiddle.net что бы было возможность глянуть на ваш код ?

Comment: Arsen, Вы помогли мне разобраться в ЧЕМ именно проблема, а проблема оказалась в конфликте бутстрапа, т.к. у меня еще был бутстрап подключен....поэтому я вопрос закрываю. Отдельное спасибо за то, что показали мне интересный инструмент, благодаря которому я нашел причину,но еще пока не поборол...

Answer (score 3):

Используйте добавление класса при клике, например:

```
<a href='page1.php' class='ajax-link'>Page 1</a>
<a href='page2.php' class='ajax-link'>Page 2</a>
<a href='page3.php' class='ajax-link'>Page 3</a>
<script>

    function loadContent(uri) {
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#content").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
    $('.ajax-link').click(function(e){
        var link = e.target;

        if (link){
            loadContent(link.href);
            $('.ajax-link').removeClass('is-active');
            $(this).addClass('is-active');
        }
    })
</script>
<style>
    .is-active {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arsen, Вы помогли мне разобраться в ЧЕМ именно проблема, а проблема оказалась в конфликте бутстрапа, т.к. у меня еще был бутстрап подключен....поэтому я вопрос закрываю. Отдельное спасибо за то, что показали мне интересный инструмент, благодаря которому я нашел причину,но еще пока не поборол...